# BeautifulSoup returning empty list

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I’m trying to create a script where I can parse the source code from https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions and retrieve the URLs of the videos in my subscription feed, in order to stick them in a MP4 download and save to my FTP server.

However I have been stuck on this problem for a couple of hours.

```
import bs4
import requests
source = requests.get('https://www.youtube.com/feed/subscriptions')
sourceSoup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source.text,'html.parser')
sourceSoup.select('#grid-319397 > li:nth-child(1) > div > div.yt-lockup-dismissable > div.yt-lockup-content > h3')
[]
```

I am right clicking on the css element and ‘inspect element’ then ‘copy selector’ and pasting it inside the select method.

As you can see, it keeps returning an empty list.

I have tried many different derivatives of this, but it’s not picking up anything. I am having the same problem when doing the same things on the homepage, therefore I doubt that it is because it is behind a login (although I am logged in on the PC in which the script is running).

Can someone please point in the right direction?

Comment: Are you sure the element exists before any JavaScript running in the browser changed the DOM? Did you look at the value of `source`?

Comment: I looked at the value of source, and when i search the output, it returns null for "#grid-319397 > li:nth-child(1) > div > div.yt-lockup-dismissable > div.yt-lockup-content > h3". This is my first language, how do i ensure it exists before JS changes the DOM, and if it does not, then what would my options be?

Comment: use youtube api's instead

Comment: As a general rule: HTTP client libraries don't execute JavaScript as the browser would. Don't take for granted that what you see in the browser is what Python sees.

Comment: @DisplayName as farther explained in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are facing 2 different (but somehow related) issues:

1. The page that the server returns to the GET reguest that is being sent by your code might be different from the page that you recieve when you go to the page with your browser, because of an unknown user-agent to the server.
2. The item you're looking for is only visible after you log-in.

Now, instead of manually taking care for both of these issues, there is a YouTube API that you should be considering to use.

A demo code showing that we get a different page for different user-agents:

```
import requests

python_user_agent_request = requests.get('http://www.youtube.com')
chrome_user_agent_request = requests.get('http://www.youtube.com',
                                         headers={'user-agent':'''Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36
                                                               (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36'''})

print(python_user_agent_request.request.headers['user-agent'])
>>  python-requests/2.7.0 CPython/3.4.2 Windows/7

print(chrome_user_agent_request.request.headers['user-agent'])
>> Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36

# .text holds the HTML page source
print(python_user_agent_request.text == chrome_user_agent_request.text)
>> False
```

Comment: Thanks DeepSpace, i will definitely look into the YouTube API.

Comment: Are you sure this is a problem of the user agent?